# Angular 2 project configuration for tomcat server

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I merged the Angular2 project(Hello World) in my existing Maven project.

While running the project, I can see "Loading..." in 'index.html'. But the dynamic values are not appending with my tag.

I hope i am missing some configuration for tomcat server. Because the same sample project is working in Angular CLI.

What can I add to run the sample with tomcat server.

Comment: can share the angular folder structure for what u done in apache server

Comment: @Sathiyaraj : I have added the src, assert, environment folders and index.html in WebContent folder. I have created new menu for Angular2-Test. I am loading the index.html, by clicking the menu.                                                                   What are the configurations I need to do for running it. As of now, it is loading html page only.